# Is there a way to dictate the number of breaks shown on a plot axis for a wide range of possible inputs in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have created a personalised y-axis that specifies breaks and labels at irregular intervals for a plot in an R Shiny application. Depending on which data I input the y-axis can either be too narrow (doesn't show enough, if any, breaks) or too wide (shows too many breaks and the labels overlap). I have tried using the `expand` functionality, however, there are no values that suit all possible inputs.  Is there a way to prevent this and to just dictate that there should be 3 breaks on the axis regardless of the inputs? I have been unable to successful implement `n.breaks` - is this the right way to go?

I have created a small demo df underneath that replicates the problem, however, the solution should apply to a much wider range of values.

```
y <- c(1 ,2, 3, 45, 63, 24)
x <- c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005)
df <- cbind(x,y)
df <- data.frame(df)


breaks <- c(1, 10, 40,60,65, 75)
labels <- c("a", "b","c", "d", "e", "f")

ggplot(data = NULL, aes(x,y, group=1)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = breaks, labels = labels)

type1 <-  filter(df, as.numeric(x) <= 2002)

ggplot(data = type1, aes(x,y, group=1)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = breaks, labels = labels)

type2 <-  filter(df, as.numeric(x) >= 2003)

ggplot(data = type2, aes(x,y, group=1)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = breaks, labels = labels, expand = expand_scale(c(0.5,0.4)))
```

Many thanks.

Comment: In your example you have two breaks at the same value (y = 1). Are you saying you want a solution that covers that possibility? If so, what would that look like? Would one of the labels be removed? Would they both be merged, dodged, ignored? There won't be a solution that covers _all possible_ inputs unless you know what you want to do with overlapping y axis labels, even with only 3 inputs (if the values were 0, 0.1 and 10,000, the first two labels will overlap). You need to decide whether to prevent certain inputs or to how to handle overlapping labels. Let us know what exactly you need

Comment: My apologies, that was a typo - now corrected. The issue would be with overlapping labels.

Comment: you have to filter the `breaks` and `labels` vactors as well.

Comment: Hi Roman, please can you explain? Is there a way to filter the breaks and labels automatically such that there are always 3 breaks on the axis?

Answer (score 1):

you can try a label function

```
foo <- function(x) {
 require(tidyverse)
  tibble(breaks, labels) %>% 
    right_join(tibble(breaks=x, n=T)) %>% 
    mutate(new = ifelse(!is.na(labels), labels, breaks)) %>% 
    pull(new)
}
ggplot(data = type1, aes(x,y, group=1)) +
     geom_line() +
     scale_y_continuous(labels = foo)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial solution to my problem which removes the overlapping labels.

```
ggplot(data = type1, aes(x,y, group=1)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = breaks, labels = labels, guide = guide_axis(check.overlap = T))
```